# How to send javascript object to C++ from qml?

Tags: javascript, c++, qml

I have a method in C++ that expects an object:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void sendValue (const MyClass &value);
```

I'd like to call this method from qml, inside a javascript function, like this:

```
MyApi.sendValue({
    "one":"one",
    "two":2.0,
    "three": false,
    "four": [ 5, 6 ],
    }
});
```

MyClass is defined as follows:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
#include <QString>
#include <QVariant>
class MyClass {
    QString one;
    double two;
    bool three;
    int four[10];
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    // getters, setters, etc.
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass)
#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

In main.cpp, MyClass is registered with `qRegisterMetaType<MyClass>();`
But none of the setters gets called, only MyClass' default constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can send javascript objects to c++ from qml via `QVariantMap` and javascript array with `QVariantList`. It also goes the other way, you can send javascript object to qml using `QVariantMap` from c++. Just make your function in c++ `Q_INVOKABLE` or a slot and have the parameter be `QVariantMap`, and convert that `QVariantMap` into `MyClass {}`.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html for details (search for QVariantList and QVariantMap to JavaScript Array and Object).

Comment: So either I parse a `QVariantMap` in the C++ method, or I define my method like this:
`Q_INVOKABLE void sendValue (const QString& one, const double two, const bool three, const QList four);`

Comment: Yep, those are the options.